# dynamic multi dimensional array alloc on gpu

Tags: c, cuda

I can alloc memory (cudaMalloc) on GPU for static multi dimensional arrays, for the ones declared as follows `int b[size1][size2][size3][size4][size5]...;`. How is it possible to alloc memory (cudaMalloc) for dynamic array on GPU, for example `int ***a;` (we can also assume higher dimensions), where `a` has all the sizes distinct? Assuming that `a` has been allocated of its dimension's sizes on CPU side. Simple example would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `cudaMalloc` does not allocate static arrays (it *always* and exclusively allocates dynamic memory). Don't confuse static objects with statically-known array sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cudaMalloc](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html) to allocate memory dynamically. For high-dimensional arrays, just compute the total, flattened size and access the array in strides:

```
void * p;
cudaError_t e = cudaMalloc(&p, dim1 * dim2 * dim3 /* ... */);
if (e != cudaSuccess) { /* error! */ }

// Access
int * arr = p;
arr[i1 * dim2 * dim3 + i2 * dim3 + i3] = 2; // etc., in strides
```

(For 2- or 3-dimensional arrays, you may also like to use [cudaMalloc3DArray](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g4a8473bad5109b6cf1794b4154cc3e0d.html#g4a8473bad5109b6cf1794b4154cc3e0d).)

There's also a corresponding host version, [cudaMallocHost](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad.html#g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad), which allocates page-locked host memory that's directly accessible by the device.

Comment: I can alloc single dimensional arrays, but what about multidimensional ones, for example "int ***v" or even higher "int ****v". thanks!

Comment: @starter: Compute the size yourself and access the array in strides. I added an example.